# The Stanford bunny - tetrahedral mesh

Tags: matlab, mesh

I am doing some research on hex-mesh generation (via polycube deformation). I would like to test my algorithm on the 3D Stanford bunny geometry. I am using Matlab for my research. I need a good quality tetrahedral mesh of the bunny, i.e. list of vertices + list of indexes of tetrahedrons in some text file. Could anyone help me with this?

I tried to search through the internet, but I have not found the data I need, i.e. list of vertices + list of indexes of tetrahedrons in some text file.

Answer (score 0):

A simple google turned up this website as the first result:

http://graphics.stanford.edu/data/3Dscanrep/

You can download the PLY file from there which has the data you need.